# Why setTitleTextAttributes is not listed as one of UITabBar Properties in the manual?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

I know we can do `setTitleTextAttributes` against `UITabBar`

It doesn't show up anywhere in:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Where can I see complete list of selectors we can send to `UITabBar` to customize it's appearance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the UITabBarItem's that declare all methods for customizing title appearance, not the UITabBar.

Methods to set the position of the title are declared in UITabBarItem: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBarItem

Methods to customize the title appearance are declared in UIBarItem (which UITabBarItem inherits from): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem

You can access an array of tab bar items via your tab bar's "items" property.